# Object oriented programming with Javascript - Constructors

Tags: javascript, oop, object, function

I've seen a lot of this...

```
function myObject(data) {
       var myData = data;
}

myObject.prototype.doSomething = function () {
      alert("I did something!");
}
```

but the intellisense on Visual Studio gives me a .constructor for functions, which would lead me to believe this would be correct...

```
function myObject() {
     var myData;

     this.constructor = function(data) {
         myData = data;
     }

     this.doSomething = function() {
         alert("I did something!");
     }
}
```

I like the encapsulation of the second method, but almost everyone uses the ".prototype".
Is there any reason for doing this in particular or is it ok to encapsulate all the classes methods like this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at:

- [Private Members in JavaScript](http://javascript.crockford.com/private.html)
- [Prototypal Inheritance in JavaScript](http://javascript.crockford.com/prototypal.html)
- [Classical Inheritance in JavaScript](http://javascript.crockford.com/inheritance.html)

Comment: You might also want to have a look at http://dean.edwards.name/weblog/2006/03/base/

Answer (score 3):

That's not at all what `constructor` does. It simply returns the function. So in your case, it would return `myObject`. For example:

```
function someObject() {
  this.a = 5;
}
var obj = new someObject();
obj.constructor; // Would return someObject
```

See [this](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_constructor_boolean.asp) for more details on the `constructor` property.

The point of using `prototype` is that you can extend constructors after they've been created. So you could use it to, for example, add a method to all String objects.

```
String.prototype.myFunc = function(){/*Some code*/};
```